# Azure IoT edge programmatically[NodeJS] create parent child relation between edge and leaf device

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I have found links from Azure GitHub repo that we can create relationship of parent child between Edge device and leaf device using [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/issues/494) and [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/286) language but I have not found the api/interface to that in NodeJS sdk provided by Azure. Has anyone implemented this in NodeJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/createorupdateidentity) there is the `deviceScope` property:

> The scope of the device. Auto generated and immutable for edge devices
> and modifiable in leaf devices to create child/parent relationship.

So try providing this property in the device object as e.g. [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/service/samples/registry_sample.js#L21) that is used for `registry.create()`

**UPDATE**: so this code works:

```
  var device = {
    deviceId: '<MY DEVICE ID>',
    deviceScope: 'ms-azure-iot-edge://<MY EDGE DEVICE ID>-xxxxxxxx'
  };

  registry.update(device, printAndContinue('update', function next(){...});
```

You can find the value of the `deviceScope` of your Edge Device in its Device Twin:

[image]

### UPDATE

If you want to remove the parent/child relationship set `deviceScope: null` in your request

Comment: Problem is my device is created through DPS and I need to just update the relationship either in device created event from grid or any other way if you can suggest?

Comment: the API is update or create...just call registry.update() https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/service/src/registry.ts#L130

Comment: What's this ```xxxxxxxx```? Is it something appended by Azure in the edge device ID?  Seems like a time stamp

Comment: xxxxxx is just a place holder for the actual value that can be found in the Device Twin and yes it looks like a time stamp to me as well.